# iText7 - Displayed text in table issue

Tags: .net, vb.net, text, itext7

I'm using **iText7** library for *.Net* and I have a very strange issue for the displayed text. Explanations:

**Context** - In my business process, there are these steps:

1. Load a PDF file from a RadDiagram (Télérik) with only one page, and save it as `Byte()` in my database. This operation can be done many times.
2. Get all PDF files from database.
3. For each PDF File, insert a table.
4. Concatenate all files inside one global file.

There is a method that I'm using in steps 1 & 3. This method will create and insert a table inside the PDF document:

```
   Private Function CreateWorkOrderHeaderTable() As Table
        Dim wLabels As Single = CSng(ReportPageSize.GetWidth * 0.06)
        Dim wValues As Single = CSng(ReportPageSize.GetWidth * 0.14)
        Dim workOrderHeaderTable As Table = New Table({ReportPageSize.GetWidth})

        Dim topHeaderTable As Table = New Table({(wLabels), (wValues), (wLabels), (wValues), (wLabels), (wValues), (wLabels), (wValues), (wLabels), (wValues)})
        topHeaderTable.SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER)

        Dim headerNames As New List(Of String)
        Dim headerValues As New List(Of String)
        Dim emptyHeaderValues As New List(Of String)(New String() {"", "", ""})
        Dim headerLabelsTable As Table
        Dim headerValuesTable As Table

        headerLabelsTable = New Table({wLabels})
        headerNames = New List(Of String)(New String() {"CA Name", "Article", "Serial #"})
        headerNames.ForEach(Sub(headerName) headerLabelsTable.AddCell(New Cell().Add(String.Format("{0} :", headerName)).SetFont(_fontArial).SetFontSize(6).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT).SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER).SetBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.LIGHT_GRAY)))
        topHeaderTable.AddCell(New Cell().SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER).Add(headerLabelsTable.SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER)))

        headerValuesTable = New Table({wValues})
        headerValues = If((Me._currentMeasure IsNot Nothing), New List(Of String)(New String() {Me._currentMeasure.CA_Name, Me._currentMeasure.JDS.DS, Me._currentMeasure.SN}), emptyHeaderValues)
        headerValues.ForEach(Sub(headerValue) headerValuesTable.AddCell(New Cell().Add(headerValue).SetFont(_fontArial).SetFontSize(6).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT).SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER)))
        topHeaderTable.AddCell(New Cell().SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER).Add(headerValuesTable.SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER)))

        headerLabelsTable = New Table({wLabels})
        headerNames = New List(Of String)(New String() {"Program", "Standard", "Desc."})
        headerNames.ForEach(Sub(headerName) headerLabelsTable.AddCell(New Cell().Add(String.Format("{0} :", headerName)).SetFont(_fontArial).SetFontSize(6).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT).SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER).SetBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.LIGHT_GRAY)))
        topHeaderTable.AddCell(New Cell().SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER).Add(headerLabelsTable.SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER)))

        headerValuesTable = New Table({wValues})
        headerValues = If((Me._currentMeasure IsNot Nothing), New List(Of String)(New String() {Me._currentMeasure.MM_Program, Me._currentMeasure.SelectedCA.Standard, Me._currentMeasure.CA_Description}), emptyHeaderValues)
        TrunkStringItems(headerValues, MAX_CHAR_BY_WORK_ORDER_PROP)
        headerValues.ForEach(Sub(headerValue) headerValuesTable.AddCell(New Cell().Add(headerValue).SetFont(_fontArial).SetFontSize(6).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT).SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER)))
        topHeaderTable.AddCell(New Cell().SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER).Add(headerValuesTable.SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER)))

        headerLabelsTable = New Table({wLabels})
        headerNames = New List(Of String)(New String() {"Station", "WorkShop", "Machine"})
        headerNames.ForEach(Sub(headerName) headerLabelsTable.AddCell(New Cell().Add(String.Format("{0} :", headerName)).SetFont(_fontArial).SetFontSize(6).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT).SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER).SetBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.LIGHT_GRAY)))
        topHeaderTable.AddCell(New Cell().SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER).Add(headerLabelsTable.SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER)))

        headerValuesTable = New Table({wValues})
        headerValues = If((Me._currentMeasure IsNot Nothing), New List(Of String)(New String() {Me._currentMeasure.Station, Me._currentMeasure.WorkShop, Me._currentMeasure.Machine}), emptyHeaderValues)
        headerValues.ForEach(Sub(headerValue) headerValuesTable.AddCell(New Cell().Add(headerValue).SetFont(_fontArial).SetFontSize(6).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT).SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER)))
        topHeaderTable.AddCell(New Cell().SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER).Add(headerValuesTable.SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER)))

        headerLabelsTable = New Table({wLabels})
        headerNames = New List(Of String)(New String() {"User", "First Name", "Last Name"})
        headerNames.ForEach(Sub(headerName) headerLabelsTable.AddCell(New Cell().Add(String.Format("{0} :", headerName)).SetFont(_fontArial).SetFontSize(6).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT).SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER).SetBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.LIGHT_GRAY)))
        topHeaderTable.AddCell(New Cell().SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER).Add(headerLabelsTable.SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER)))

        headerValuesTable = New Table({wValues})
        headerValues = If((Me._currentMeasure IsNot Nothing), New List(Of String)(New String() {Me._currentMeasure.Login, Me._currentMeasure.FirstName, Me._currentMeasure.LastName}), emptyHeaderValues)
        headerValues.ForEach(Sub(headerValue) headerValuesTable.AddCell(New Cell().Add(headerValue).SetFont(_fontArial).SetFontSize(6).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT).SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER)))
        topHeaderTable.AddCell(New Cell().SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER).Add(headerValuesTable.SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER)))

        headerLabelsTable = New Table({wLabels})
        headerNames = New List(Of String)(New String() {"MSN", "WO #", "State"})
        headerNames.ForEach(Sub(headerName) headerLabelsTable.AddCell(New Cell().Add(String.Format("{0} :", headerName)).SetFont(_fontArial).SetFontSize(6).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT).SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER).SetBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.LIGHT_GRAY)))
        topHeaderTable.AddCell(New Cell().SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER).Add(headerLabelsTable.SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER)))

        headerValuesTable = New Table({wValues})
        headerValues = If((Me._currentMeasure IsNot Nothing), New List(Of String)(New String() {Me._currentMeasure.MSN, Me._currentMeasure.WorkOrder, GetMeasureStatus()}), emptyHeaderValues)
        headerValues.ForEach(Sub(headerValue) headerValuesTable.AddCell(New Cell().Add(headerValue).SetFont(_fontArial).SetFontSize(6).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT).SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER)))
        topHeaderTable.AddCell(New Cell().SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER).Add(headerValuesTable.SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER)))

        workOrderHeaderTable.AddCell(New Cell().Add(topHeaderTable).SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER))
        workOrderHeaderTable.SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER)

        Return workOrderHeaderTable
    End Function
```

And I'm using it like this:

```
tableHeader.AddCell(New Cell().Add(CreateWorkOrderHeaderTable()).SetBorder(Borders.Border.NO_BORDER))
```

Before the save in database, and after convert `Byte()` from the database in a new PDF file, the result is: [image: here]

**Expected result** - [image: here]

**Issue** - My problem is when I'm calling this method in the step 3. I'm calling it for data reasons (set the values). The table is at the good place, with the good background color and size, but there is a big problem with the text:
[image: here]

Moreover, this same method is called for another page (which is not loaded from the database) in the step 3, and I have the expected result.

To by-passed this problem, I tried to write all texts with Paragraph object, and not Table and Cell objects like actually. And I have the same problem ([image: here] => I should to have "*CA Name*")

I think that there is a problem with the text encoding from database or a problem with the superposition (table and PDF file from `Byte()`)
The fonts are registered with the same manner.

I hope anybody can help me.

Comment: To me this looks like a subset font is used which has already before been serialized, so that glyphs which had not been used at the time of serialization are missing. Unfortunately your code is not self contained, and neither have you shared a sample PDF. Thus, I cannot check one way or the other.

Comment: @mkl : Before steps 1 & 2, I did RegisterAllFonts and register a new font that it is Arial (**used font** in my screenshots) like : `PdfFontFactory.RegisterSystemDirectories()` and `PdfFontFactory.CreateFont("c:\windows\fonts\Arial.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, True)`. The same methods are used before and after saving in the database. - What code do you need to help you ?

Comment: @mkl : I found another thing > In the first part, I created a footer written with the **Arial** font. This footer containing some characters (letters and numbers), and I can see that the_ not existing letters_ in this footer _are not visible_ in the header. My above examples are generated the 16 February 2018, and this date is wrote in the footer. In the screeshot, you can see the '6' char. Today, we are the 19th, and the '9' char is visible, **but not the '6' char** !

Comment: *"What code do you need to help you"* - I'd need code I can run as is to reproduce the issue. You only show one method but not how it's used, and even this method uses not only its parameters but also some class member variables. As your next comment suggests, you could verify that the issue has to do with font usage after serialization. From your code I cannot recognize whether your font usage pattern is wrong or whether iText has an issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to by-pass the problem (but if someone has a better solution, I appreciate) :

**Problem :** like said *@mkl*, and I confirmed this with some tests, characters which do not exist before the serialization, their will not be visible after conversion from database if I'm trying to write them.

**By-passing :**

1. I created a `string` containing a lot of each usable character (min & maj letters, numbers and special characters in my case).
2. I created a `Paragraph` object with these values : *Black* for `FontColor`, *0.001* for `FontSize`, *0* for `X position`, *0* for `Y position`, *200* for `Width`.
3. I added this paragraph in each PDF page.

... And the bug is fixed.

**I repeat, it's not the solution, and I can't explain why there is this bug,  but it's a workable way.**